# PHP Function that contains SQL query not working

Tags: php, function, sqlsrv

I'm attempting to put together a function that will perform SQL queries as part of a code cleanup I'm doing. The query works outside of the function, but inside the function I get no results. Here's the applicable code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<body>
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
require_Once'../connect.php';
function callQuery($select,$from,$where){
    $pull=array();
    $query="SELECT ".$select." FROM ".$from." WHERE ".$where;
    $run=sqlsrv_query($conn,$query);
    while($result=sqlsrv_fetch_array($run,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $resultS=var_dump($result);
    }   
return $query;
return $resultS;
}


echo callQuery("HDCaseNum","HDCase","HDCaseNum='8818'");

?>
</html></body>
```

The code is just a test setup to get the concept down.

***EDIT***
This is what I was trying to accomplish:

```
function callQuery($select,$from,$where,$conn){
    $resultS=array();
    if($where){$where="WHERE $where";}
    $query="SELECT ".$select." FROM ".$from." ".$where;
    $run=sqlsrv_query($conn,$query);
    while($result=sqlsrv_fetch_array($run,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
        array_push($resultS,$result);
    }   
return $resultS;
}
```

I pass in the columns, table(s) and filters and it spits out a multidimensional array of results. Keeps me from having to retype all the sqlsrv functions over and over again.

Comment: `var_dump` returns `void`, you never use the `$pull` variable, and you're returning a string.  What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: You have 2 return statements, var_dumpm has no return value.

Comment: The `header()` call below of HTML makes no sense either.

Comment: The header() call was to make sure I wasn't getting cached results. var_dump wasn't returning anything because I failed to pass the $conn variable into the function to make the connection to the sql server. Simple mistake.

Comment: `header` calls must be placed before **any** output. At this place of code, it had no effect.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'll fix that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `$conn` as one parameter of the function too.

Comment: That did it! I didn't even think about that. I assumed that because it was a global variable passed from the connect.php page it would be available to the function.  Thank you!